# Index causing parameter error between two sheets, GOOGLE SHEETS

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, range, google-sheets-formula

first time question asker here. This is on google sheets!
In attached picture, Sheet 13 is on the right. Sheet on the left is where the equation is being typed and we can call it sheet 1.
Here is my equation:

```
=INDEX(Sheet13!G:G,MATCH(N2781, Sheet13!A:A,0),MATCH(K2781,Sheet13!D:D,0))
```

the #NUM! error happens when I drag down the equation, seems like only the top value of sheet 13 (on the right of the photo) the index will only view the top one (top size, 36? The only match I could get was for the cells that matched sheet 13 row 1.

How do I get this to drag down and not be limited by this error? I am down to use a new equation as well.

[image: Reference photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example:  Your `Index` is trying to return the **9<sup>th</sup> Row** and **2<sup>nd</sup> Column** of range `G:G`.  The second of one columns is a Reference Error.

If what you want is where Column A *and* column B match your inputs, then you need something like this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet13!G:G,MATCH(1,(N2781=Sheet13!A:A)*(K2781=Sheet13!D:D),0))
```

What this does is create a long (*very* long - you may want to limit the Range, instead of using the whole column) array which is `1` when both values match, and `0` when they don't.  It then hunts through for the first row where this Array is `1`

Now, if each Pairing of a columns A and D is **unique**, *and* column G is **always a number**, then you can use `SUMIFS` instead:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet13!G:G, Sheet13!A:A, N2781, Sheet13!D:D, K2781)
```

Much simpler!

Comment: I guess I am only intermediate at excel, I really thought my equation made sense. You are a life saver, I will put sumifs on my list of things to learn. Works perfect!